# Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

I have a web form which works fine until you keep on working on it. But if you leave it for 20 mins, on submit button click it gives the following error

[image]
Error

It seems to me the page request object gets NULL but exactly cant reach to the issue.
I have tried to increase the session timeout at IIS but it did not help.

Please help me to know the root cause for it.

Thanks all

Comment: What does the code in `btnSubmit_Click` look like?

Comment: You might want to consider posting some code. I would be very surprised if anyone can help you with this without it. I would strongly suggest the btnSubmit_Click code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing some code one can only guess, but I think that `btnSubmit_Click` tries to use an object that is stored in the `Session`. Because of the long idle time, the session has timed out, and clicking the button causes the request to get a new session, in which this object is not yet assigned.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. Is there any way we can control session from timing out?

Comment: @Priyanka: sessions will time-out eventually so increasing the timeout limit will only move the problem. You will need to handle it more gracefully. One way is to store the form in a temporary session variable before processing it; if the session has timed out, establish a new one (including redirecting the user to login page or similar). When the new session is established and configure, use the temporary session variable to restore the form, and the user can resume work. That is just a quick idea (and perhaps not the best); there are many ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a check on the page load event:

for example:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["emp_num"] != null)
            {
                empNum = int.Parse(Session["emp_num"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                //Go To The Home Page(Login Page)
            }
        }
```

**You can make this check in the Masterpage.cs**